# Flink 1.12.0 on yarn doesn't recognize yn

Tags: apache-flink

I used the following script to submit my application on yarn.

```
MAIN_CLASS=org.example.app.HelloFlink
flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 4 -ys 1 -ynm FlinkHiveIntegrationTest -c $MAIN_CLASS /learn.flink.ioc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

It complains that `Could not get job jar and dependencies from JAR file: JAR file does not exist: -yn`.

When I remove the `-yn 4` in the script,then it works. I have used `-yn` in previous flink version to specify the number of containers. So, how could I specify the number of containers for Flink 1.12.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-yn` option was deprecated by FLIP-6, and has been ignored since the legacy runtime was removed in Flink 1.8. Now this option is no longer recognized by the CLI; see [FLINK-12362](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12362).

Instead, the ResourceManager will automatically launch as many containers as are needed to satisfy the parallelism requested by the job.

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson for the helpful answer!